# What should be our domain name?

Tags: discussion, top-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/162/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline)

### Note:

We are closing this domain naming thread. It is asking the *entirely* wrong question. See this blog post for details: [Domain Names: Wrong Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/)

We're going to keep the name gis.stackexchange.com. But we WILL be setting up redirects from the more "popular" domains names (e.g. seasonedadvice.com to cooking.stackexchange.com, basicallymoney.com to money.stackexchange.com, and others as we go through the list).

New question: "**Write and Elevator Pitch / Tagline!**"

[**Click here to contribute ideas and vote.**](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/162/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline)

*[original message text below]*

---

Please suggest domain names, remember that Stack Overflow Inc. might put up some cash if needed, so squatted domains aren't really off the mark.

Place your suggestions each in an answer and please inform of the status (unregistered/squatted/in active use/abandoned)

Answer (score 24):

### invalidgeometry.com

Available (held).

Reasoning: the original Stack Overflow was named after the common [technical problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow), similarly invalid geometries are a specific issue commonly encountered by users of GIS.

Comment: this is also a good name.

Comment: I love it......

Comment: I quite like this too, despite a general dislike for the "failure mode" names.

Comment: does it need to be squatted?

Comment: OK, I've registered the domain, and happy to pass it off to the proper authorities if we do settle on it.

Comment: @scw: Thank you for reserving it. For future reference, I am happy to register any domains that show signs of momentum/usability.

Comment: Great idea, +1 from me.

Answer (score 4):

spatialoverflow.com
spatialexception.com

Comment: +1 spatialoverflow

Answer (score 3):

outofbounds.com ?

Answer (score 2):

spatialmind.* - available

Comment: drat, should have held it myself. It's gone now. Whoever you are, I hope you put it to real use! :)

Answer (score 2):

### OblateSpheroid.com

Comment: This is my take on a geo-unique domain name.  I personally don't like the link to the "mother site", and the SO folks have made it clear that they'd like the StackExchange sites to create their own brands. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/domain-names/

Comment: Im never gonna remember that!

Comment: @SpoiledTechie well, I was going to go with geoid, but it was taken and oblate spheroid was a close-enough approximation :)  (maybe this was too much of an in-joke?)

Comment: I had a mental block for remembering Stack Overflow for the longest time.  I had to google for it every time.

Comment: Definitely my favourite :)

Answer (score 1):

gis.info - personal site, in use, but redirects to http://gisinfo.tistory.com/ so perhaps could be persuaded to let it go? Anyone here read/write korean?

Answer (score 1):

gismind.com - taken, personal, not actively used (refers to [DynDNS](http://www.dyndns.com/))
gismind.org, .net, .info - available

Answer (score 1):

impossiblegeometry.com

Answer (score 0):

gis-mind.* - all available

Answer (score 0):

geometryintersection.com (available)
spatialintersection.com (available)

Answer (score -1):

http://geomancers.com/ (squatted)

Answer (score -1):

gis-knowledge.* - all available
gisknowledge - only .org and .info available

Answer (score -1):

## mapemundi.com

..................

Answer (score -1):

http://opaqueoverlay.com

(available)

Comment: intereting one.

Answer (score -1):

### hicsuntdracones.com

It's squatted, but is a nice oblique [geography reference](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/927/great-gis-maps-cartography-quotes/960#960). Hard to type / remember however.

Answer (score -2):

searchingforsatellites.com

(not registered)

Comment: makes me think the site would focussed on remote sensing